# Cube refresh with Automation Account in Azure SSAS

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm currently trying to create an automation runbook to process a cube in Azure. I've tried multiple PowerShell scripts like this one :

```
$AzureCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "RefreshTest"
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCred | Out-Null
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MKTGCube" -server "AzureServerName" -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $AzureCred
```

With that kind of error (despite the fact that I installed the SQLServer module).

> Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : The term 'Invoke-ProcessASDatabase' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is
>
> correct and try again.

Or this script :

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

##Getting the credential which we stored earlier.
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'CredMat'

## Providing the Server Details
$ServerName = "AzureServerName"


Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MKTGCube" -server $ServerName –ProcessType "ProcessFull" 

$error[0].Exception.Message
$error[0].Exception.StackTrace
```

With that error message.

> Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Authentication failed: User ID and Password
>   are required when user interface is not
>
> available.
>
> At line:32 char:1
>
> - Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MKTGCube" -server $ServerName ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ProcessASDatabase], ArgumentException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessASDatabase

I think the problem is linked to the credentials because we need to provide ones to access the source database but I have no ideas on how to do it through a PowerShell script. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The root reason is that you should use `Login-AzureASAccount` to login not `Add-AzureRmAccount`, they are different. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import module `Azure.AnalysisServices` and `SqlServer` to your automation account.

You could import these two module from this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.AnalysisServices/0.5.0) and this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17224).

[image]

Note: There is a mistake in your script. You should use `Login-AzureASAccount` not `Add-AzureRmAccount` to login, you could use the following example:

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection 
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment "southcentralus.asazure.windows.net" -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint -TenantId $Conn.TenantID 
Invoke-ProcessTable -Server "asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/myserver" -TableName "MyTable" -Database "MyDb" -RefreshType "Full"
```

More information about this please check this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's not working unfortunatelly. I have that error message now : 

Login-AzureASAccount : The term 'Login-AzureASAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 

file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 

and try again.

Comment: Do you import module `Azure.AnalysisServices`? You could use `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount` to login.

Comment: See my update answer, `Login-AzureASAccount` is a alias for `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount`, you need import module `Azure.AnalysisServices` firstly, import the module from this https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.AnalysisServices/0.5.0

Comment: I imported the module but the error is always about `Login-AzureASAccount` or `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount`

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of my actual error : 
http://fr.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24vnvyu&s=9#.WruYMH_Lipo

And the link of my code : 
http://fr.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6oolc9&s=9#.WruZC3_Lipo

Comment: @MatRic You should use Connection `AzureRunAsConnection`, in your other connection, there is no application id in it, so you will get the error log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167780/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-matric).