# Invoke-ASCmd : Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-automation, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to refresh credentials of an (already)deployed Tabular Model via CICD using Azure DevOps.
Making use of **Invoke-ASCmd** in PowerShell to refresh the credentials. The script works fine from local when I provide the Tenant ID, App ID and the Key. However it fails when I run it from Azure Devops with error - User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available.
Here is the script:

```
$azureTenantId= "TenantId"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Key" -AsPlainText -Force
$azureAplicationId ="AppID"

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 

Invoke-ASCmd `
    -Server "AnalysisServerName" `
    -Database "AdventureWorks" `
    -Query "{
  ""createOrReplace"": {
    ""object"": {
      ""database"": ""AdventureWorks"",
      ""dataSource"": ""AzureBlobs/https://abc blob core windows net/""
    },
    ""dataSource"": {
      ""type"": ""structured"",
      ""name"": ""AzureBlobs/https://abc blob core windows net/"",
      ""connectionDetails"": {
        ""protocol"": ""azure-blobs"",
        ""address"": {
          ""account"": ""abc"",
          ""domain"": ""blob.core.windows.net""
        },
        ""authentication"": null,
        ""query"": null
      },
      ""credential"": {
        ""AuthenticationKind"": ""Key"",
        ""kind"": ""AzureBlobs"",
        ""path"": ""https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/"",
        ""PrivacySetting"": ""Organizational"",
        ""Key"": ""Key""
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

Comment: Is this [post](https://github.com/avdbrink/VSTS-SSAS-Extension/issues/4) helpful to your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Module Azure.AnalysisServices
$azureappid ="tesappid"
$azureTenantId= "testid"

[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $userPassword = "testpwd"

$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $azureappid, $userPassword
    
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment 'eastus.asazure.windows.net' -Credential $userCredential -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 

Invoke-Ascmd ....
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I am getting AADSTS7000011 when I am using service principal, do we need any special configuration for the service principal? Later, I tried with my credentials, I am getting error AADSTS7000016. Do I need any specific permission for my credentials? Please reply, and please complete Invoke-Ascmd in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount` to login to an instance of Azure Analysis Services server. See below:

```
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
    
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment 'eastus.asazure.windows.net' -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 

Invoke-ASCmd ...
```

Check document [Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.analysisservices/add-azureanalysisservicesaccount?view=azurermps-5.7.0) for more information. See this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507272/cube-refresh-with-automation-account-in-azure-ssas).

You can also try providing the credentials for Invoke-ASCmd command:

```
Invoke-ASCmd -Server "" -Database "" -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal -Query ""
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Added some extra code at the beginning to get rid of the argument issue.

Comment: Levi Lu-MSFT - AzureDevOps uses a different IP address every time I run the script, If I whitelist one, the next time it tries to deploy with different IP address. Do you have a work around for this?