# AzureDevops deploys Analysis Sevices with different IP address everytime

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-analysis-services

I am deploying Tabular Model via CICD, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997541/invoke-ascmd-authentication-failed-user-id-and-password-are-required-when-use/64002865#64002865) approach , however every time it deploys using different IP addresses. I have to disable the firewall rule in Azure Analysis Services for deployment. Is there any workaround for this or a specific IP range to whitelist?

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Self-hosted agent:**

You can configure one specific [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) for deployment purpose, so that you only need to add the IP address of the agent machine to allow list.

**For Microsoft-hosted agent:**

And if you prefer to using cloud-hosted agents, you need to **dynamically** modify the firewall rule in each continuous deployment.

(Since every time you get a new hosted agent instance, you then get a different IP address.)

We can use a [Azure Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) right before the deploy task to configure the firewall rule of your Analysis Service. About how to write the content of PS script, you can refer to [AddDevOpsIpToAAS.ps1](https://github.com/ArthurSteijn/AzureAnalysisServicesFirewallScripts) for some help.

Here's one [detailed blog](https://medium.com/@Arthur86S/how-to-add-your-devops-ip-to-azure-analysis-services-firewall-962652cd5b36) from **Arthur** about "How to add your DevOps IP to Azure Analysis Services Firewall", it should be helpful for you. (Thanks to **Arthur**!)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. I have tried this approach, but the IP address returned by this script differs from the acutal IP address used Invoke-ASCmd. For example if the script returned IP Address (made up) 1.1.1.10 then I still get the error "Cannot connect to server 'aasblahblahblah'. Client with IP Address '1.1.1.11' is not allowed to access the server". Some times it one higher and sometimes its one lower, e.g. 1.1.1.11 or 1.1.1.9